# pass arguments to tmuxinator project file

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

I have a project file like

```
windows:
  - server:
      layout: even-vertical
      panes:
        - ssh -t {pass value in here} tail -f -n 100 /var/log/app.log
        -
```

I would like to pass the SSH host in as I start the session. Something like

```
mux project for.bar
```

Can this be done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout [this section](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator#erb) Tmuxinator's readme.

> You can also pass arguments to your projects, and access them with
> ERB. Simple arguments are available in an array named @args.
>
> Eg:
>
> $ tmuxinator start project foo
>
> *~/.tmuxinator/project.yml*
>
> name: project root: ~/<%= @args[0] %>
>
> ... You can also pass key-value pairs using the format key=value.
> These will be available in a hash named @settings.
>
> Eg:
>
> $ tmuxinator start project workspace=~/workspace/todo
>
> *~/.tmuxinator/project.yml*
>
> name: project root: ~/<%= @settings["workspace"] %>
>
> ...